# Structure lco files in subdirectories

Tags: koma-script, scrletter

lco files usually are placed in `~/texmf/tex/latex/`.

An lco file `~/texmf/tex/latex/ich.lco` would then be referenced in the actual document (in this case with Koma script) as

```
\LoadLetterOption{ich}
```

However I'd like to structure my lco files a bit more and put them in some subdirectories, therefore placing the lco file in `~/texmf/tex/latex/senders/ich.lco` and would like to reference it via

```
\LoadLetterOption{senders/ich}
```

But apparently, that does not work. I also found nowhere a hint about whether it is possible to use subdirectories in `~/texmf/tex/latex` or not.

It this possible?

If yes, what do I have to put in the lco files `\ProvidesFile` directive? And what do I have to put into the corresponding `\LoadLetterOption` directive?

Comment: you should be able to use sub directories with no change in the tex, the directory path is recursively searched to all subdirectories (by default)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Damn! You're right, of course! I made a silly typing mistake when trying that out and didn't notice it. So I thought it would not be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use sub directories with no change in the tex document. The directory path is recursively searched to all subdirectories (by default).